# How to calculate percentage difference of geometric means with emmeans?

Tags: lsmeans, geometric-mean

I want to estimate the estimated marginal means (EMMs) of a log-normal variable across different groups. Let’s take the dataset of `pigs` from `emmeans` package for example. I first build a linear model taking the `log(conc)` as response variable and `source` and `percent` as predicator variables. Then, passing the model to the function of `emmeans()`. The EMMs can be back-transformed to the original scale with the argument of `type=”response”`. In the result, except for the EMMs, I also get the contrasts between groups, with a `ratio` column representing the `exponential(mean difference of log value)`. But I want to get the value of `100* exponential(mean difference of log value) -100`, which is more frequently presented in articles. I know I can get this value by extracting the `ratio` column and doing a little transformation, but how can I get the confidence interval?

```
library(emmeans)
data(pigs)
fit1 <- lm(log(conc)~source+factor(percent),data=pigs)
emmeans(fit1,spec= pairwise~source,type="response",infer=T)
```

Comment: It's a linear transformation, so just do the same thing to the confidence limits.

Comment: You should be compute the ratio of geometric means.

Comment: @frankharrell that *is* what Kyle was getting, and the question is how to get CLs for the percent differences of the GMs.

Comment: The the title of the post needs editing.

Comment: True. I suggest "how to compute percentage difference ..."

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it using the **emmeans** package. It involves creating an "identity" contrast, and using the `scale` and `offset` arguments. An example using the `pigs` dataset follows:

```r
library(emmeans)

pigs.lm = lm(log(conc) ~ source * factor(percent), data = pigs)
EMM = emmeans(pigs.lm, ~ percent | source, type = "response")
PRS = pairs(EMM)

# custom contrast function:
iden.emmc = function(levs, ...) {
    M = as.data.frame(diag(length(levs)))
    names(M) = levs
    M
}

confint(contrast(regrid(PRS), "iden", scale = 100, offset = -100, 
                 estName = "pct.diff"))
## source = fish:
##  contrast pct.diff    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  (9/12)    -16.877  8.82 17    -35.5     1.73
##  (9/15)    -17.251  9.62 17    -37.5     3.05
##  (9/18)    -20.549  8.43 17    -38.3    -2.76
##  (12/15)    -0.449 10.57 17    -22.7    21.84
##  (12/18)    -4.418  9.07 17    -23.6    14.72
##  (15/18)    -3.986 10.19 17    -25.5    17.51
## 
## source = soy:
##  contrast pct.diff    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  (9/12)    -13.166  8.24 17    -30.6     4.22
##  (9/15)    -12.274  8.33 17    -29.8     5.29
##  (9/18)    -19.782 10.77 17    -42.5     2.94
##  (12/15)     1.027  9.59 17    -19.2    21.26
##  (12/18)    -7.619 12.40 17    -33.8    18.55
##  (15/18)    -8.558 12.28 17    -34.5    17.34
## 
## source = skim:
##  contrast pct.diff    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  (9/12)    -18.480  7.74 17    -34.8    -2.15
##  (9/15)    -29.114  7.52 17    -45.0   -13.24
##  (9/18)    -41.167  7.90 17    -57.8   -24.50
##  (12/15)   -13.045  9.23 17    -32.5     6.43
##  (12/18)   -27.830  9.69 17    -48.3    -7.39
##  (15/18)   -17.004 11.82 17    -41.9     7.93
## 
## Confidence level used: 0.95
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Note that we had to also use `regrid(PRS)` because the ratios are not actually stored as such in the `PRS` object -- just the instructions for how to summarize it.

#### Another approach

Another approach is to replace the log transformation with a custom one that back-transforms to the desired values:

```r
mytran = list(
    linkfun = function(mu) log(mu/100 + 1),
    linkinv = function(eta) 100 * (exp(eta) - 1),
    mu.eta = function(eta) 100 * exp(eta),
    name = "pct.diff tran"
)

update(PRS, tran = mytran, inv.lbl = "pct.diff", infer = TRUE)
## source = fish:
##  contrast pct.diff    SE df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
##  9 / 12    -16.877  8.82 17    -38.5    12.39  -1.742  0.3339
##  9 / 15    -17.251  9.62 17    -40.5    15.16  -1.629  0.3897
##  9 / 18    -20.549  8.43 17    -41.2     7.43  -2.168  0.1723
##  12 / 15    -0.449 10.57 17    -26.4    34.60  -0.042  1.0000
##  12 / 18    -4.418  9.07 17    -27.0    25.19  -0.476  0.9634
##  15 / 18    -3.986 10.19 17    -29.0    29.82  -0.383  0.9802
## 
## source = soy:
##  contrast pct.diff    SE df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
##  9 / 12    -13.166  8.24 17    -33.7    13.73  -1.487  0.4662
##  9 / 15    -12.274  8.33 17    -33.0    14.90  -1.380  0.5281
##  9 / 18    -19.782 10.77 17    -45.2    17.49  -1.642  0.3829
##  12 / 15     1.027  9.59 17    -22.9    32.32   0.108  0.9995
##  12 / 18    -7.619 12.40 17    -36.9    35.30  -0.590  0.9336
##  15 / 18    -8.558 12.28 17    -37.6    33.93  -0.666  0.9082
## 
## source = skim:
##  contrast pct.diff    SE df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
##  9 / 12    -18.480  7.74 17    -37.8     6.77  -2.152  0.1767
##  9 / 15    -29.114  7.52 17    -47.6    -4.15  -3.242  0.0225
##  9 / 18    -41.167  7.90 17    -59.8   -13.83  -3.952  0.0051
##  12 / 15   -13.045  9.23 17    -35.7    17.57  -1.317  0.5651
##  12 / 18   -27.830  9.69 17    -50.7     5.70  -2.430  0.1090
##  15 / 18   -17.004 11.82 17    -44.6    24.40  -1.309  0.5699
## 
## Confidence level used: 0.95 
## Conf-level adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
## Intervals are back-transformed from the pct.diff tran scale 
## P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
## Tests are performed on the pct.diff tran scale
```

This produces the same estimates, but different confidence intervals. The reason is that the intervals (and tests) are still performed on the scale of the fitted model, rather than using the SEs of the ratios that we obtain after applying `regrid(PRS)` in the previous solution. For that reason, this latter method produces the same confidence limits as we'd get by converting the original limits to the percent-difference scale:

```
with(confint(PRS), 100*(lower.CL - 1))
##  [1] -38.52415 -40.53746 -41.24007 -26.37452 -27.02186 -28.99035 ...
```

Hence I think that this latter approach is "better."

Comment: BTW, you can add `parens = NULL` to remove the parentheses that `contrast` adds to the levels.

Comment: @kyle Please see the addendum to my answer. It is a better method.

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RussLenth would it be correct to include a bias adjustment in the update() line of this code?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be OK