# percentage of difference with estimated marginal means

Tags: r, cross-validation, group-differences, contrasts, lsmeans

I am calculating the difference between concentration of different metabolites according to the factor sex (male/female) and age group (<55 / >=55) from this linear model:

```
model <- lm(metabolite ~ agegroup + sex, data =df)
emmeans(model, "agegroup")


sex = 0:
 agegroup emmean     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
        0  0.329 0.0291 2499    0.272    0.386
        1  0.373 0.0327 2499    0.308    0.437

sex = 1:
 agegroup emmean     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
        0 -0.490 0.0303 2499   -0.549   -0.430
        1 -0.446 0.0377 2499   -0.520   -0.372

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Now I want to calculate the percentage of difference of male vs. female by age group and plot it. I am trying this

```
mean_diff_sex <- as.data.frame(emmeans::contrast(emmeans(model, "sex")))

 contrast   estimate         SE   df   t.ratio       p.value
1 0 effect -0.5206612 0.01737366 2499 -29.96842 7.576451e-169
2 1 effect  0.5206612 0.01737366 2499  29.96842 7.576451e-169
```

However, I am not sure if I can transform this estimate into the percentage of difference doing: **((2^estimate)-1)x100** or it would be better to using: **Absolute difference / Average x 100**

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [a recent answer to a similar question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/551843/52554), in particular the last half of it. This also inspired an [vignette example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/transformations.html#altscale) along the same lines.

However, you need to have your estimates on the log scale first. For example, fit the model with `log(metabolite)` as the response.